# What is the difference between HttpResponseMessage and HttpResponseException

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I tried to understand both and write sample code:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get()
 {
     var response = ControllerContext.Request
                         .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "abc");

     throw new HttpResponseException(response);
 }
```

And:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get()
 {
     return ControllerContext.Request
                        .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "abc");
 }
```

From Fiddle, I really didn't see any differences between them, so what is the purpose of using `HttpResponseException`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Throw HttpResponseException or return Request.CreateErrorResponse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519561/throw-httpresponseexception-or-return-request-createerrorresponse)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The main difference between the two is this. The exception is useful to immediately stop processing and exit. For example assume I have the following code

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController {
  private ICustomerContext repo;

  public CustomerController(ICustomerContext repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
  }

  public Customer Get(int id) {
    var customer = repo.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c=>c.CustomerID == id);
    if (customer == null) {
      throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }
    return customer;
  }
}
```

If this code runs and I pass an id that is not present, it will immediately stop processing and return a status code of 404.

If instead I return HttpResponseMessage, the request will happily continue the rest of its processing and return a 404. The main difference being end the request or not.

As Darrel said the exception is useful in cases where in some cases I want processing to continue (as in when customer is found) and in others I don't.

The place where you might want to use something like HttpResponseMessage is in an Http POST to return a status code of 201 and set the location header. In that case I do want processing to continue. That would would do with this code.*

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController {
  private ICustomerContext repo;

  public CustomerController(ICustomerContext repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
  }

  public HttpResponseMessage Post(Customer customer) {
    repo.Add(customer);
    repo.SaveChanges();
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, customer);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, string.format("customer/{0}", customer.id));
    return response;
  }
}
```

*note: If you are using the beta bits you would create a new HttpResponseMessage. I am using the later bits however which require you to use the CreateResponse extension method off of the Request.

Above, I am creating a response which sets the status code to 201, passes in the customer, and then sets the location header.

The response is then returned and the request continues processing.

Hope this helps

Comment: I would add that exception-handling/logging is another reason. You may want to throw to log a 404 but not throw and not log a 412.

Comment: I'm really confused by what you mean with "the request continues processing". Isn't the request finished the moment you `return`?

Comment: @Stijn - there's some comments on Glenn's blog (http://goo.gl/ErSG9h) that make it a little bit clearer. It sounds like Glenn is referring to processing that Web.Api does after the controller returns such as Message Handlers. However, Steven Solomon questions whether that's the case or not.

Comment: @Iain thanks for the link, it's an interesting comment. It's not that I don't believe Glenn, but it'd be great if he could demonstrate the difference.

Comment: @GlennBlock I am not sure this is the right answer.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862244/does-returning-ihttpactionresult-stop-request-execution/19863507) seems to differ

Answer (score 28):

HttpResponseException is useful when your Controller Action signature looks like

```
  Foo Get(int id)
```

In this case, you cannot easily return status code like 400.

Be aware that `HttpResponseMessage<T>` is going away in the next release of Web API.

Comment: Only the generic HttpResponseMessage<T> is going away

Comment: @ozba  Thanks, I hadn't noticed that the markup syntax prevented the angle brackets from appearing.

Comment: This is also the case referred to in `Professional ASP.Net MVC 4`, http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-4.productCd-111834846X.html. When your API is based around returning domain types like `Foo`, you can't return an `HttpResponseMessage` in the case of an error but you can return/throw `HttpResponseException` and thus provide status codes etc to the consumer. Why would you want to return domain types? Well in contrast to some other answers here, they say it simplifies UT dealing with domain objects rather than low level framework objects like `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: @rism HttpResponseMessage isn't a "low level framework" object, it is an object that represents the HTTP message your are returning.  HTTP is an application level protocol.  You don't return objects over HTTP, you return HTTP messages.  Attempting to pretend that you are returning domain objects will cause much pain in the long run.

Comment: O.k. well you'll have to take it up with Brad Wilson, his words `However, returning a response object is a fairly
low-level operation, so Web API controllers almost always return a raw object value (or sequence of
values) instead.` ... `This ability to return a raw object is very powerful, but we’ve lost something with the shift away
from ActionResult; namely, the ability to return different values for success and failure.` Personally I'd pick and choose on a case by case basis but given there is so much built in support for `HttpResponseMessage`, it seems there is little reason not to use it.

Comment: @rism IHttpActionResult is a reasonable compromise http://www.bizcoder.com/composing-api-responses-for-maximum-reuse

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you want to unit test the responses, doesn't it make sense to always return an HttpResponseMessage? I don't particularly like the idea of returning a straight type from an ApiController since it doesn't follow typical development patterns.

In a non-Web API class that fetched a Customer, you'd likely return null, with your calling code checking for a null response:

```
public Customer GetCustomer(int id)
{
    return db.Customers.Find(id);
}
```

But in Web API, you're not going to return null, you have to return something, even if that something is created after you throw an HttpResponseException. In that case, to ease testing, why not just always return an HttpResponseMessage, and make that your signature?

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetCustomer(int id)
{
    var customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
    if (customer == null)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customer);
}
```

Comment: I agree, Brian. This also makes for a better learning path for returning objects and status codes. When the template sets a return type as a business object, it makes you wonder what the proper way is to deal with other responses.

Comment: @Brian it is a style thing.  Some people want to get knee deep in HTTP and feel like it is part of their application design.  Others feel HTTP is an implementation detail and would rather abstract away the HTTPness using ActionFilters and HttpMessageHandlers.  Neither approach is wrong if you know what you are doing.  I tend to take your approach because I feel hiding the HTTP makes things look too much like RPC.

Comment: This is the way I naturally fell into doing it. It called WebAPI - so to me it makes perfect scene that it should always return a valid HTTP Response - and that response tells the caller what happened.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpResponseException` derives from `Exception` and embeds `HttpResponseMessage`.
Since it derives from `Exception` it can be useful in `try`-`catch` scenarios.

Default status code returned by `HttpResponseException` is `HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError`.

Answer (score 0):

As the original questions states, there is no real difference in the returned Response.

The real purpose of HttpResponseException is to allow sub methods to create and 'throw' their own HttpResponseMessages that flow back to the up the call stack and are returned to the client.

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController {
  private ICustomerContext repo;
  public CustomerController(ICustomerContext repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
  }

  public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id) {

    Customer customer = getCustomer(id);

    return Request.CreateResponse(customer);
  }

  private Customer getCustomer(int id){
    .....do some work
    .....we have a problem so throw exception
    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Id out of range");
    return repo.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c=>c.CustomerID == id)
}
```

Forgive any mistakes, code written on the fly. The thrown HttpResponseException bubbles up thru the actions call stack, does not get caught by normal Exception handlers and returns its HttpResponseMessage like the action method itself would have.