# ASP.NET Web API return HttpResponseMessage or throw error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've been looking into writing a web service using the .net Web APIs, but I'm seeing two different approaches to sending error messages. The first is to return an `HttpResponseMessage` with the appropriate `HttpStatusCode` set, something like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage<string> Get() 
{ 
      ...
      // Error!
      return new HttpResponseMessage<string>(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized); 
}
```

And the other method is to just throw an `HttpResponseException`, like this:

```
public Person Get(int id)
{
     if (!_contacts.ContainsKey(id))
     {
         throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, String.Format("Contact {0} not found.", id)));
     }

     return _contacts[id];
}
```

Are there any advantages/disadvantages to using either one? And in terms of scalability and performance, is either one better than the other?

Comment: Read Glenn Block's explanation [What is the difference between HttpResponseMessage and HttpResponseException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660721/what-is-the-difference-between-httpresponsemessage-and-httpresponseexception)

Comment: ah, I didn't see that post.  That does help a lot!  thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is curious which direction I went, I went with `HttpResponseException` for several reasons:

- It makes the code more readable to someone who is not as familiar with WebAPIs (Most people know that when you throw an exception, something went wrong)
- In my tests `HttpResponseExceptions` return faster, YMMV
- It's easier to Unit Test (just Assert that an exception was thrown)