# Throw HttpResponseException or return Request.CreateErrorResponse?

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api, http-status-codes

After reviewing an article [Exception Handling in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling) I am a bit confused as to when to throw an exception vs return an error response. I am also left wondering whether it is possible to modify the response when your method returns a domain specific model instead of `HttpResponseMessage`...

So, to recap here are my questions followed by some code with case #s:

## Questions

### Questions regarding Case #1

1. Should I always use `HttpResponseMessage` instead of a concrete domain model, so that the message can be customized?
2. Can the message be customized if you are returning concrete domain model?

### Questions regarding Case #2,3,4

3. Should I be throwing an exception or returning error response? If the answer is "it depends", can you give situations/examples on when to use one vs the other.
4. What is the difference between throwing `HttpResponseException` vs `Request.CreateErrorResponse` ? The output to client seems identical...
5. Should I always use `HttpError` to "wrap" response messages in errors (whether the exception is thrown or error response returned)?

## Case Samples

```
// CASE #1
public Customer Get(string id)
{
    var customer = _customerService.GetById(id);
    if (customer == null)
    {
        var notFoundResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        throw new HttpResponseException(notFoundResponse);
    }
    //var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customer);
    //response.Content.Headers.Expires = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300));
    return customer;
}        

// CASE #2
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
{
    var customer = _customerService.GetById(id);
    if (customer == null)
    {
        var notFoundResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        throw new HttpResponseException(notFoundResponse);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customer);
    response.Content.Headers.Expires = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300));
    return response;
}

// CASE #3
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
{
    var customer = _customerService.GetById(id);
    if (customer == null)
    {
        var message = String.Format("customer with id: {0} was not found", id);
        var errorResponse = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
        throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customer);
    response.Content.Headers.Expires = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300));
    return response;
}

// CASE #4
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
{
    var customer = _customerService.GetById(id);
    if (customer == null)
    {
        var message = String.Format("customer with id: {0} was not found", id);
        var httpError = new HttpError(message);
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, httpError);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customer);
    response.Content.Headers.Expires = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300));
    return response;
}
```

## Update

To help further demonstrate cases #2,3,4 the following code snippet highlights several options that "can happen" when a customer is not found...

```
if (customer == null)
{
    // which of these 4 options is the best strategy for Web API?

    // option 1 (throw)
    var notFoundMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    throw new HttpResponseException(notFoundMessage);

    // option 2 (throw w/ HttpError)
    var message = String.Format("Customer with id: {0} was not found", id);
    var httpError = new HttpError(message);
    var errorResponse = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, httpError);
    throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse);

    // option 3 (return)
    var message = String.Format("Customer with id: {0} was not found", id);
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
    // option 4 (return w/ HttpError)
    var message = String.Format("Customer with id: {0} was not found", id);
    var httpError = new HttpError(message);
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, httpError);
}
```

Comment: @Mike Wasson As the author of the linked article, which approach would you take?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The approach I have taken is to just throw exceptions from the api controller actions and have an exception filter registered that processes the exception and sets an appropriate response on the action execution context.

The filter exposes a fluent interface that provides a means of registering handlers for specific types of exceptions prior to registering the filter with global configuration.

The use of this filter enables centralized exception handling instead of spreading it across the controller actions. There are however cases where I will catch exceptions within the controller action and return a specific response if it does not make sense to centralize the handling of that particular exception.

**Example registration of filter:**

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(
    new UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute()
    .Register<KeyNotFoundException>(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)

    .Register<SecurityException>(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)

    .Register<SqlException>(
        (exception, request) =>
        {
            var sqlException = exception as SqlException;

            if (sqlException.Number > 50000)
            {
                var response            = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                response.ReasonPhrase   = sqlException.Message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty);

                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
    )
);
```

**UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace Sample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the an attribute that provides a filter for unhandled exceptions.
    /// </summary>
    public class UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        #region UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute()
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute() : base()
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region DefaultHandler
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a delegate method that returns an <see cref="HttpResponseMessage"/> 
        /// that describes the supplied exception.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// A <see cref="Func{Exception, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage}"/> delegate method that returns 
        /// an <see cref="HttpResponseMessage"/> that describes the supplied exception.
        /// </value>
        private static Func<Exception, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage> DefaultHandler = (exception, request) =>
        {
            if(exception == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var response            = request.CreateResponse<string>(
                HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, GetContentOf(exception)
            );
            response.ReasonPhrase   = exception.Message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty);

            return response;
        };
        #endregion

        #region GetContentOf
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a delegate method that extracts information from the specified exception.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// A <see cref="Func{Exception, String}"/> delegate method that extracts information 
        /// from the specified exception.
        /// </value>
        private static Func<Exception, string> GetContentOf = (exception) =>
        {
            if (exception == null)
            {
                return String.Empty;
            }

            var result  = new StringBuilder();

            result.AppendLine(exception.Message);
            result.AppendLine();

            Exception innerException = exception.InnerException;
            while (innerException != null)
            {
                result.AppendLine(innerException.Message);
                result.AppendLine();
                innerException = innerException.InnerException;
            }

            #if DEBUG
            result.AppendLine(exception.StackTrace);
            #endif

            return result.ToString();
        };
        #endregion

        #region Handlers
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the exception handlers registered with this filter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// A <see cref="ConcurrentDictionary{Type, Tuple}"/> collection that contains 
        /// the exception handlers registered with this filter.
        /// </value>
        protected ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Tuple<HttpStatusCode?, Func<Exception, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage>>> Handlers
        {
            get
            {
                return _filterHandlers;
            }
        }
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Tuple<HttpStatusCode?, Func<Exception, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage>>> _filterHandlers = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Tuple<HttpStatusCode?, Func<Exception, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage>>>();
        #endregion

        #region OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the exception event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actionExecutedContext">The context for the action.</param>
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            if(actionExecutedContext == null || actionExecutedContext.Exception == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var type    = actionExecutedContext.Exception.GetType();

            Tuple<HttpStatusCode?, Func<Exception, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage>> registration = null;

            if (this.Handlers.TryGetValue(type, out registration))
            {
                var statusCode  = registration.Item1;
                var handler     = registration.Item2;

                var response    = handler(
                    actionExecutedContext.Exception.GetBaseException(), 
                    actionExecutedContext.Request
                );

                // Use registered status code if available
                if (statusCode.HasValue)
                {
                    response.StatusCode = statusCode.Value;
                }

                actionExecutedContext.Response  = response;
            }
            else
            {
                // If no exception handler registered for the exception type, fallback to default handler
                actionExecutedContext.Response  = DefaultHandler(
                    actionExecutedContext.Exception.GetBaseException(), actionExecutedContext.Request
                );
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Register<TException>(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
        /// <summary>
        /// Registers an exception handler that returns the specified status code for exceptions of type <typeparamref name="TException"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TException">The type of exception to register a handler for.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="statusCode">The HTTP status code to return for exceptions of type <typeparamref name="TException"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// This <see cref="UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute"/> after the exception handler has been added.
        /// </returns>
        public UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute Register<TException>(HttpStatusCode statusCode) 
            where TException : Exception
        {

            var type    = typeof(TException);
            var item    = new Tuple<HttpStatusCode?, Func<Exception, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage>>(
                statusCode, DefaultHandler
            );

            if (!this.Handlers.TryAdd(type, item))
            {
                Tuple<HttpStatusCode?, Func<Exception, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage>> oldItem = null;

                if (this.Handlers.TryRemove(type, out oldItem))
                {
                    this.Handlers.TryAdd(type, item);
                }
            }

            return this;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Register<TException>(Func<Exception, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage> handler)
        /// <summary>
        /// Registers the specified exception <paramref name="handler"/> for exceptions of type <typeparamref name="TException"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TException">The type of exception to register the <paramref name="handler"/> for.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="handler">The exception handler responsible for exceptions of type <typeparamref name="TException"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// This <see cref="UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute"/> after the exception <paramref name="handler"/> 
        /// has been added.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="handler"/> is <see langword="null"/>.</exception>
        public UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute Register<TException>(Func<Exception, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage> handler) 
            where TException : Exception
        {
            if(handler == null)
            {
              throw new ArgumentNullException("handler");
            }

            var type    = typeof(TException);
            var item    = new Tuple<HttpStatusCode?, Func<Exception, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage>>(
                null, handler
            );

            if (!this.Handlers.TryAdd(type, item))
            {
                Tuple<HttpStatusCode?, Func<Exception, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage>> oldItem = null;

                if (this.Handlers.TryRemove(type, out oldItem))
                {
                    this.Handlers.TryAdd(type, item);
                }
            }

            return this;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Unregister<TException>()
        /// <summary>
        /// Unregisters the exception handler for exceptions of type <typeparamref name="TException"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TException">The type of exception to unregister handlers for.</typeparam>
        /// <returns>
        /// This <see cref="UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute"/> after the exception handler 
        /// for exceptions of type <typeparamref name="TException"/> has been removed.
        /// </returns>
        public UnhandledExceptionFilterAttribute Unregister<TException>()
            where TException : Exception
        {
            Tuple<HttpStatusCode?, Func<Exception, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage>> item = null;

            this.Handlers.TryRemove(typeof(TException), out item);

            return this;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Source code can also be found [here](http://codepaste.net/zf26na).

Comment: wow! :) This may be a bit much for smaller projects, but still very nice...BTW, why CreateResponse instead of CreateErrorResponse in DefaultHandler?

Comment: I was attempting to separate the error details (serialized in the body) from the reason phrase; but you could certainly use CreateErrorResponse if that made more sense like in the case of model binding.

Comment: Since you can register the filter with just one line of code, I think it is suitable for almost any project type. We have the filter in a class library that is published on our internal NuGet feed, so it is easy for developers to use.

Comment: What are you using for guards (homegrown or 3rd party)?

Comment: Hoemgrown, I removed its use in the example above. The Guard class provides a set of static methods that guard against or verify that an assertion has been met. See http://codepaste.net/5oc1if (Guard) and http://codepaste.net/nsrsei (DelegateInfo) if you want the implementation.

Comment: Was my answer satisfactory, or do I need to provide additional information?

Comment: if there are other global filters, this would have to be the first one added. Correct? Also, when would you unregister the exceptions? I have been testing this and so far it plays nicely...BTW, in your DefaultHandler you can use `                    var includeErrorDetail = false;
#if DEBUG includeErrorDetail = true; #endif
var httpError = new HttpError(exception, includeErrorDetail);
return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, httpError);`

Comment: new HttpError serializes nicely (I think uses conneg) and there is no need for GetContentOf anymore :) --- Sorry for code blip, I could not resist :)

Comment: Unregister method is just for parity, you should be able to add/remove handlers as you see fit, but typically you would only add them prior to filter registration. Thanks for the feedback, feel free to edit the example code if you think it can be improved.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17253/discussion-between-zam6ak-and-oppositional)

Comment: thumb up, anyway I'll post another answer extending your solution (here i've no enough chars availables)

Comment: If you make it so that the filter is configured only on startup then you can use the non-concurrent collections to reduce performance cost (or the ImmutableCollections). I don't see a lot of scenarios that involve registering new filters while the application is running. I appreciate the register syntax simplicity; perhaps a params[] Func for intialization? Just throwing ideas out there; I do something very similar but a little more simple currently. Great answer, as is.

Answer (score 30):

If you are not returning **HttpResponseMessage** and instead are returning entity/model classes directly, an approach which I have found useful is to add the following utility function to my controller

```
private void ThrowResponseException(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
{
    var errorResponse = Request.CreateErrorResponse(statusCode, message);
    throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse);
}
```

and simply call it with the appropriate status code and message

Comment: This is the right answer, it comes with the format "Message" as a key value pair in the body. This is typically how I see other frameworks and languages do it

Comment: I have a minor question about this approach. I'm consuming the message using {{}} syntax in the angularJS page. If I leave carriage returns, they come as n\r\ in the message. What is the right way to preserve them?

Comment: I tried this approach. I did `throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid Request Format!"))`, but in Fiddler, it shows status 500 (not 400). Any idea why?

Comment: the difference is the parent function of the error. Here is the ThrowResponseException for any exception in the application. But should be the real function throwing the exception...

Answer (score 21):

**Do not throw an HttpResponseException or return an HttpResponesMessage for errors - *except* if the intent is to *end the request* with *that exact result***.

HttpResponseException's are *not handled the same as other exceptions*. They are *not caught in Exception Filters*. They are *not caught in the Exception Handler*. They are a sly way to slip in an HttpResponseMessage while terminating the current code's execution flow.

Unless the code is infrastructure code relying on this special un-handling, *avoid* using the HttpResponseException type!

HttpResponseMessage's are not exceptions. They do not terminate the current code's execution flow. They can *not* be filtered as exceptions. They can *not* be logged as exceptions. They represent a valid result - even a 500 response is "a valid non-exception response"!

---

Make life simpler:

When there is an exceptional/error case, go ahead and throw a normal .NET exception - or a customized application exception type (*not* deriving from HttpResponseException) with desired 'http error/response' properties such as a status code - as per *normal exception handling*.

Use Exception Filters / Exception Handlers / Exception Loggers to do something appropriate with these exceptional cases: change/add status codes? add tracking identifiers? include stack traces? log?

By avoiding HttpResponseException *the 'exceptional case' handling is made uniform* and can be handled as part of the exposed pipeline! For example one can turn a 'NotFound' into a 404 and an 'ArgumentException' into a 400 and a 'NullReference' into a 500 easily and uniformly with application-level exceptions - while allowing extensibility to provide "basics" such as error logging.

Comment: I understand why `ArgumentException`s in a controller would logically be a 400, but what about `ArgumentException`s deeper in the stack? It wouldn't necessarily be correct to turn these into 400, yet if you have a filter that blanket converts all `ArgumentException`s to 400, the only way to avoid that is to catch the exception in the controller and re-throw something else, which seems to defeat the purpose of uniform exception handling in a filter or similar.

Comment: @cmeeren In the code I was dealing it, most of it caught the exception and turned it into the HttpResponse[Exception/Message] in each web-method. Both cases *are the same*, in that if the concern is to do something different with internal exceptions that is done doing "something" with the caught internal exception: I recommend the result is to throw an appropriate wrapping exception that is still handled further up the stack.

Comment: @cmeeren After updates, most of our web entry points throw a special derived (non-HttpResponseException, that have and or are mapped to appropriate response codes) to usage errors. The uniform handler could do some stack inspection (icky, but it works with some care) to determine at what level the exception came from - ie. cover 99% of the cases that do not have more refined handling - or simply respond with a 500 for internal errors. The crux with HttpResponseException is that it bypasses useful pipeline processing.

Answer (score 18):

Case #1

1. Not necessarily, there are other places in the pipeline to modify the response (action filters, message handlers).
2. See above -- but if the action returns a domain model, then you can't modify the response *inside* the action.

Cases #2-4

1. The main reasons to throw HttpResponseException are:

   - if you are returning a domain model but need to handle error cases,
   - to simplify your controller logic by treating errors as exceptions
2. These should be equivalent; HttpResponseException encapsulates an HttpResponseMessage, which is what gets returned back as the HTTP response.

   e.g., case #2 could be rewritten as

   ```
   public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
   {
       HttpResponseMessage response;
       var customer = _customerService.GetById(id);
       if (customer == null)
       {
           response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
       }
       else
       {
           response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customer);
           response.Content.Headers.Expires = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300));
       }
       return response;
   }
   ```

   ... but if your controller logic is more complicated, throwing an exception might simplify the code flow.
3. HttpError gives you a consistent format for the response body and can be serialized to JSON/XML/etc, but it's not required. e.g., you may not want to include an entity-body in the response, or you might want some other format.

Comment: The approach I have taken is to just throw exceptions from the api controller actions and I have registered an exception filter that processes the exception and sets an appropriate response on the action execution context. The filter is 'pluggable' such that I can register handlers for specific types of exceptions prior to registering the filter with global configuration. This allows me to do centralized exception handling instead of spreading it across the controllers.

Comment: @Oppositional Any chance you would be willing to share your exception filter? Perhaps as a Gist or on a code share site such as CodePaste?

Comment: @Mike Wasson would you say that "return error response" is more common approach vs "throw exception"? I understand functionally the end result may be (is?) the same, but I am wondering why not just encompass entire controller logic in try/catch and return error response as appropriate?

Answer (score 9):

Another case for when to use `HttpResponseException` instead of `Response.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)`, or other error status code, is if you have transactions in action filters and you want the transactions to be rolled back when returning an error response to the client.

Using `Response.CreateResponse` will not roll the transaction back, whereas throwing an exception will.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I want to point out that it has been my experience that if throwing an HttpResponseException instead of returning an HttpResponseMessage in a webapi 2 method, that if a call is made immediately to IIS Express it will timeout or return a 200 but with a html error in the response. 
Easiest way to test this is to make $.ajax call to a method that throws a HttpResponseException and in the errorCallBack in ajax make an immediate call to another method or even a simple http page. You will notice the imediate call will fail. If you add a break point or a settimeout() in the error call back to delay the second call a second or two giving the server time to recover it works correctly. This makes no since but its almost like the throw HttpResponseException causes the server side listener thread to exit and restart causing a split second of no server accepting connections or something.</strike>

Update: *The root cause of the wierd Ajax connection Timeout is if an ajax call is made quick enough the same tcp connection is used. I was raising a 401 error ether by returning a HttpResonseMessage or throwing a HTTPResponseException which was returned to the browser ajax call. But along with that call MS was returning a Object Not Found Error because in Startup.Auth.vb app.UserCookieAuthentication was enabled so it was trying to return intercept the response and add a redirect but it errored with Object not Instance of an Object. This Error was html but was appended to the response after the fact so only if the ajax call was made quick enough and the same tcp connection used did it get returned to the browser and then it got appended to the front of the next call. For some reason Chrome just timedout, fiddler pucked becasue of the mix of json and htm but firefox rturned the real error.  So wierd but packet sniffer or firefox was the only way to track this one down.*

Also it should be noted that if you are using Web API help to generate automatic help and you return HttpResponseMessage then you should add a

```
[System.Web.Http.Description.ResponseType(typeof(CustomReturnedType))]
```

attribute to the method so the help generates correctly. Then

```
return Request.CreateResponse<CustomReturnedType>(objCustomeReturnedType)
```

or on error

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse( System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new Exception("An Error Ocurred"));
```

Hope this helps someone else who may be getting random timeout or server not available immediately after throwing a HttpResponseException.

Also returning an HttpResponseException has the added benefit of not causing Visual Studio to break on an Un-handled exception usefull when the error being returned is the AuthToken needs to be refreshed in a single page app.

<strike>Update:  I am retracting my statement about IIS Express timing out, this happened to be a mistake in my client side ajax call back  it turns out since Ajax 1.8 returning $.ajax() and returning $.ajax.().then() both return promise but not the same chained promise then() returns a new promise which caused the order of execution to be wrong. So when the then() promise completed it was a script timeout. Weird gotcha but not an IIS express issue a problem between the Keyboard and chair.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, whether you throw an exception, or you return Request.CreateErrorResponse, the result is the same.  If you look at the source code for System.Web.Http.dll, you will see as much.  Take a look at this general summary, and a very similar solution that I have made: [Web Api, HttpError, and the behavior of exceptions](http://blog.codeishard.net/2013/02/09/webapi-and-the-behavior-of-exceptions-and-an-alternative-configurable-way-to-deal/)

Answer (score 0):

I like [Oppositional answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12533662/1716620)

Anyway, I needed a way to catch the inherited Exception and that solution doesn't satisfy all my needs.

So I ended up changing how he handles OnException and this is my version

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) {
   if (actionExecutedContext == null || actionExecutedContext.Exception == null) {
      return;
   }

   var type = actionExecutedContext.Exception.GetType();

   Tuple<HttpStatusCode?, Func<Exception, HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage>> registration = null;

   if (!this.Handlers.TryGetValue(type, out registration)) {
      //tento di vedere se ho registrato qualche eccezione che eredita dal tipo di eccezione sollevata (in ordine di registrazione)
      foreach (var item in this.Handlers.Keys) {
         if (type.IsSubclassOf(item)) {
            registration = this.Handlers[item];
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   //se ho trovato un tipo compatibile, uso la sua gestione
   if (registration != null) {
      var statusCode = registration.Item1;
      var handler = registration.Item2;

      var response = handler(
         actionExecutedContext.Exception.GetBaseException(),
         actionExecutedContext.Request
      );

      // Use registered status code if available
      if (statusCode.HasValue) {
         response.StatusCode = statusCode.Value;
      }

      actionExecutedContext.Response = response;
   }
   else {
      // If no exception handler registered for the exception type, fallback to default handler
      actionExecutedContext.Response = DefaultHandler(actionExecutedContext.Exception.GetBaseException(), actionExecutedContext.Request
      );
   }
}
```

The core is this loop where I check if the exception type is a subclass of a registered type.

```
foreach (var item in this.Handlers.Keys) {
    if (type.IsSubclassOf(item)) {
        registration = this.Handlers[item];
        break;
    }
}
```

my2cents

Answer (score 0):

In error situations, I wanted to return a specific error details class, in whatever format the client requested instead of the happy path object.

I want to have my controller methods return the domain specific happy path object and to throw an exception otherwise.

The problem I had was that the HttpResponseException constructors do not allow domain objects.

This is what I eventually came up with

```
public ProviderCollection GetProviders(string providerName)
{
   try
   {
      return _providerPresenter.GetProviders(providerName);
   }
   catch (BadInputValidationException badInputValidationException)
   {
     throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                                          badInputValidationException.Result));
   }
}
```

`Result` is a class that contains error details, while `ProviderCollection` is my happy path result.