# Request.CreateResponse vs returning POCOs in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I see a lot of samples on the web for ASP.NET Web API that use `Request.CreateResponse` to generate responses. If you create a new Web API project in Visual Studio, the default API controllers return `IEnumerable<string>` or `string`. What's the difference in usage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519561/asp-net-web-api-throw-httpresponseexception-or-return-request-createerrorrespon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a `HttpResponseMessage` allows you to control all different aspects of the returned HTTP response directly.  If you return a POCO you have to hope that the framework does what you want.  And maybe it will, and maybe it won't.

Comment: ok that makes sense. Has either one evolved to be the preferred choice at this point?

Comment: @qntmfred I have preferred returning HTTPResponseMessage since day one.  Some people prefer the idea of returning objects.  Web API was intended to be a framework without opinions (other than HTTP) that allows you to choose how it will behave.

Answer (score 0):

Request.CreateResponse can generate other http message, ex.`404`,`500`.
If just return,the http message will be `200 OK`.

In my code, if get need authorized, I will return like this:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

write this,you unnecessary change the return value.