# AngularJS & WebAPI - get error message from the 400 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

why can't I read the error message in AngularJS from the following code

```
ModelState.AddModelError("field", "error");

return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

or

```
return BadRequest("error message");
return Content(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { field = "error"});
```

all I get when I catch that error is

```
    { 
        data: "Bad request", 
        status: 400, headers: ..... , 
        config: //POST method config, 
        statusText: "Bad Request" 
    }
```

Comment: Does your response object have a `response` property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get error message on BadRequest in Web Api 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544340/cant-get-error-message-on-badrequest-in-web-api-2)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I saw I had the config line:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="myMode" existingResponse="Replace">
```

and it should be

```
<httpErrors errorMode="myMode" existingResponse="PassThrough">
```