# How to catch an error coming back from an ASP.NET MVC wep api?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app that calls a Wep API. The Web API throws an exception but not sure how to catch it.

The Web API catches an error and throws it.

[image]

The ASP.NET MVC web app method that calls the Web API.

The "Try Catch" did not catch the error.

The line:

```
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
```

shows the status code is NOT successful so it falls into the false condition which just puts a friendly message into the viewbag.

Instead, I want to be able to something here in order to make the `Error.cshtml` to appear.

How do I throw the error message at this point to get the `Error.cshtml` to appear? The page has appeared under other error scenarios. I believe by having the 'HandleErrorAttribute' in the `Filter.config.cs` file.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetUserProfile()
    {
        if ((string)@Session["HasProfileSwitch"] == "False")
        {
            UserProfileForMaintViewModel userProfileForMaintViewModel = new UserProfileForMaintViewModel();
            return View("UserProfileMaint1", userProfileForMaintViewModel);
        }
        else
            try
            {
                string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
                string myIpAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList[2].ToString();
                UserProfileForMaintViewModel userProfileForMaintViewModel = new UserProfileForMaintViewModel();

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56224");
                    string restOfUrl = "/api/profileandblog/getuserprofile/" + Session["UserName"] + "/" + myIpAddress + "/" + Session["UserId"];
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    // Call the web api - HTTP GET.
                    HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(restOfUrl);

                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var userResponse = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        userProfileForMaintViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfileForMaintViewModel>(userResponse);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // The web api sent an error response.
                        ViewBag.errormessage = "Server error on getting the active userProflie. UserId: " + Session["UserId"] + " Please contact the administrator.";                          
                    }

                    return View("UserProfileMaint1", userProfileForMaintViewModel);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what I have in the FilterConfig.cs - the `ErrorLoggerAttribute` points to a custom error logger.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using GbngWebClient.Helpers;

namespace GbngWebClient
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new ErrorLoggerAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `Error.cshtml`:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Error";
Layout = null;
}

<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />

 <style>
   .center {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
  }
</style>

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="hero-unit center">
                <h1>
                    Something Went Wrong!
                </h1>

                @if (TempData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
                {
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>Oops!</strong> @TempData["ErrorMessage"]
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        An error occurred while processing your request.
                    </div>
                }

            <br />
            <p>Contact the Administrator.</p>
            <p><b>To go back home, just press this button:</b></p>
            <a href="/Home/Index" class="btn btn-large btn-info"><i class="icon-home icon-white">
            </i>Take Me Home</a>
            </div>
           <br />
           <p></p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note: Never rethrow an exception using `throw ex;`. Instead use `throw;` The latter preserves the stack trace so you can see where the exception originated from. `throw ex;` will reset the stack trace in the exception to the point where that is being called.

Comment: Igor..actually that was the way I originally had it but was trying things before I realized that the local 'try catch' was not catching the error as explained above. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: You should be `await`ing the call to `ReadAsStringAsync()` instead of accessing the `Result` property of the `Task` directly. Also, your `else` block is unnecessary, as is the nesting it adds, as you're returning early if the original `if` condition is matched.

Comment: Not sure how to code that. I tried but ran into compile errors. My code works fine for most of my test cases. Except when there is an error to catch. So I think it is sound generally. I took these 2 examples as reference. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consuming-asp-net-web-api-rest-service-in-asp-net-mvc-using-http-client/ https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/consume-web-api-get-method-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Maybe your questions is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519561/throw-httpresponseexception-or-return-request-createerrorresponse).