# Can I throw a HttpResponseException from a console app?

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api, console-application, httpresponse

I have a console app which receives a rest response, when that response is a 401 or 400 can/should I throw the HttpResponseException here, even though that requires installing the Asp.Net.WebApi.Core package into the project?

Or is there a better alternative? Not sure if it's okay to mix things from web api into a console app

Comment: Could you provide a code sample of the app?

Comment: This answer might be able to help you[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519561/throw-httpresponseexception-or-return-request-createerrorresponse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having a greater picture of your use case I would consider creating a custom exception that contains the data you might need for proper error handling.
I can imagine having `HttpStatusCode` property for the status code in the response and a `string` property that would contain the body of the response. Maybe also some dictionary to save the headers you would find needed. See below for an example.

Note that it is a good practise to make custom exceptions serializable, i.e. add the `[Serializable]` attribute, implement the protected constructor and the override of the `GetObjectData` method. I tried to add some XML documentation to the example code to explain.

You may find quite a few articles that describe good practices when designing custom exception, e.g. [here](https://blog.gurock.com/articles/creating-custom-exceptions-in-dotnet/).

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom exception that describes a problem indicated by a remote web API
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public class RemoteApiException : Exception
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the HTTP status code provided in the response
    /// </summary>
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the response body content data as string
    /// </summary>
    public string? Body { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and initializes a new exception that describes a problem indicated by a remote web API
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message associated with the exception</param>
    /// <param name="statusCode">The status code in the HTTP response from the remote web API</param>
    /// <param name="body">The content of the response body</param>
    public RemoteApiException(string message, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string? body)
        : base(message)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Body = body;
    }

    #region Serialization related members

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor that is used by the serializer when deserializing the exception
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="info">The information associated with the serialization process</param>
    /// <param name="context">The context of the serialization</param>
    protected RemoteApiException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)info.GetInt32(nameof(StatusCode));
        Body = info.GetString(nameof(Body));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enriches the serialization info with the custom property values when serializing the exception
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="info">The serialization information data</param>
    /// <param name="context">The context of the serialization</param>
    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
        info.AddValue(nameof(StatusCode), (int)StatusCode, typeof(int));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Body))
        {
            info.AddValue(nameof(Body), Body, typeof(string));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```