# return status code Unauthorized for custom IActionFilter in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I am working with asp.net WebAPI and I need to create a custom ActionFilter that does a quick check to see if the user requesting the URI should actually be able to get data back.

They have already been authorized to use the web service via basic auth and their role has been validated via a custom role provider.

The last thing I need to do is to check that they have permission to view the data they are requesting with a parameter in their URI.

Here is my code:

```
public class AccessActionFilter : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
        {

            var result = //code to see if they have permission returns either 0 or 1

            if (result==0) {
               throw new ArgumentException("You do not have access to this resource");
            }
            return continuation();
        }
    }
```

Currently I just throw an error which is not what I want, I'd rather return `System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized` but I am a little miffed by the method I am overriding and I do not really understand it completely.

How would I go about returning that value?

Comment: Since authorization isn't just missing, but rather an identity has been provided but the user doesn't have access, the proper HTTP response is 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are probably best sticking to an exception but using the HttpResponseException which will return an Http status code too.

```
throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
```

Good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660721/what-is-the-difference-between-httpresponsemessage-and-httpresponseexception) about this.

p.s.

It may be simpler/cleaner to implement `ActionFilterAttribute`

```
public class AccessActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var result = //code to see if they have permission returns either 0 or 1

        if (result==0) 
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
```

}

Comment: This violates HTTP 1.1. It says a [401 error](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) must provide a `WWW-Authenticate` to indicate an acceptable scheme. `ApiController.Unauthorized` has a parameter for this. Fortunately, this isn't a problem with 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Throwing exceptions is expensive, so wouldn't this make it easier to attack the server by sending many invalid attempts and making a load on the server from the overhead of theHttpResponseExceptions thrown? Or perhaps the bandwidth from multiple requests is the bottle neck anyway so it wouldn't have a significant affect?

Comment: @BornToCode all exceptions like this will be caught in the HttpControllerDispatcher (http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch12.html#_apicontroller_processing_model) in a fairly simple try catch looking specifically for HttpResponseException - I am not sure how expensive they really are likely to be - As always I would suggest testing it out in a harness and measuring - i would be surprised if the difference would be an issue - take a peek at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891217/how-expensive-are-exceptions-in-c as well to decide whether exceptions really are "expensive"

Answer (score 8):

Instead of throwing exception you can set status code

```
public class ExecutionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var result = 0;//code to see if they have permission returns either 0 or 1

        if (result == 0)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                Content = new StringContent("Unauthorized User")
            };
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the valid answer ✅